# How to download pdf file without opening the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, browser

This code i am trying but without any error it not showing anything for me.

```
if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
    var save = document.createElement('a');
    save.href = fileURL;
    save.target = '_blank';
    save.download = fileName || 'unknown';

    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    save.dispatchEvent(event);
    (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
}

// for IE
else if ( !! window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand)     {
    var _window = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
    _window.document.close();
    _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
    _window.close();
}
```

This is not working for me

Comment: What do you mean "without opening the browser"? Isn't that code running in a browser?

Comment: Where is `fileName` defined ? Is requirement to open and download a blank `html` document as `pdf` ?

Comment: It means file has not to be open in browser it should direct download.

Comment: By this code file is opening in browser and again i have to save it. So i need a code which can directly download the file.

Comment: _"i need a code which can directly download the file"_ Yes, what file should be downloaded ?

Comment: I am using this code in a function where i am passing fileName and Url as a parameter.

Comment: function SaveFile(Url, fileName) { // Given code }

Answer (score 1):

Try appending `save` element to `document.body` using `.appendChild()` before calling `event.initEvent('click', true, true)` , `save.dispatchEvent(event)`

```js
var fileURL = "data:text/plain,abc", fileName = "file.txt";

if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
    var save = document.createElement('a');
    save.href = fileURL;
    save.target = '_blank';
    save.download = fileName || 'unknown';
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    // append `a` element : `save` to `document.body` here
    document.body.appendChild(save);
    event.initEvent('click', true, true);
    save.dispatchEvent(event);
   //  (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
}
```

Comment: File not downloaded.

Comment: Can describe you describe _"File not downloaded"_ ? , create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?

Comment: This code is working in google crome but in firefox it is giving a popup for save file.

Comment: @MohitSingh The expected result is "Save file" dialog displayed to user. Cannot force user to download file ; or download file to a specific location at users filesystem

Comment: Expected result is download the file to the file system by given any url

Comment: @MohitSingh You want to bypass the browsers "Save file" dialog ?

Comment: Yes sir. that is the only thing i need